# How do you handle column names having spaces in them when using pd.read_clipboard?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, clipboard

This is a real problem I've faced for a long time.

Take this dataframe:

```
         A         B  THRESHOLD
       NaN       NaN        NaN
 -0.041158 -0.161571   0.329038
  0.238156  0.525878   0.110370
  0.606738  0.854177  -0.095147
  0.200166  0.385453   0.166235
```

It is easy enough to copy using `pd.read_clipboard`. However, if one of the column names has a space:

```
         A         B     Col #3
       NaN       NaN        NaN
 -0.041158 -0.161571   0.329038
  0.238156  0.525878   0.110370
  0.606738  0.854177  -0.095147
  0.200166  0.385453   0.166235
```

Then, it is read like this:

```
          A         B       Col  #3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN NaN
1 -0.041158 -0.161571  0.329038 NaN
2  0.238156  0.525878  0.110370 NaN
3  0.606738  0.854177 -0.095147 NaN
4  0.200166  0.385453  0.166235 NaN
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: What I usually do is I try to make sure that columns are separated by more than one space. This way, I can use something like `df = pd.read_clipboard(header=0, sep="\s{2,}", engine="python")`. Both atom and sublime text will allow you to search and replace in regex; which should help.

Comment: @Abdou Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: I've been wondering for awhile now how everyone else handles these. Thanks for turning it into a question.

Comment: @Abdou Yeah... `pd.read_clipboard` is that tool everyone uses but no one talks about... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do in this situation is that I make all my columns two or more spaces apart, then I use sep='\s\s+' for my delimiter, this way when I do have column headings with a single space such as, Col #3 above it treats it as one column.

```
         A         B     Col #3
       NaN       NaN        NaN
 -0.041158  -0.161571   0.329038
  0.238156   0.525878   0.110370
  0.606738   0.854177  -0.095147
  0.200166   0.385453   0.166235

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
```

You do get this warning, but you can ignore it since it as done it right. Or you could put the `engine='python'` if your OCD gets the best of you. :)

> C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\clipboards.py:63:
>   ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c'
>   engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and
>   different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this
>   warning by specifying engine='python'.   return
>   read_table(StringIO(text), sep=sep, **kwargs)

```
print(df)

          A         B    Col #3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 -0.041158 -0.161571  0.329038
2  0.238156  0.525878  0.110370
3  0.606738  0.854177 -0.095147
4  0.200166  0.385453  0.166235
```

Comment: When you say you make them 2 spaces apart, you mean you paste it in a notepad and manually enter those spaces?

Comment: Okay this is similar to what Abdou says and it makes sense. I have more issues which I'll ask in future questions but this answer addresses this one, so thanks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Generally, I always put sep='\s\s+' when I see heading with a space or dates with time because there is usually date space time, and this is treated as a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re`, `io` and `pd.read_table` to drive the point I was making in the comments, I copied the exact text you have in the post, applied a first round of `re.sub` to remove any leading whitespace. Then, I replaced any space that is preceded by a number--this is unique to the case at hand since the column names are mostly string characters--with 2 spaces. Once all that is done, I converted the resulting string into an `io.StringIO` object and fed the latter to the `pd.read_table` function. This essentially the same thing as copying the text and pasting it in `sublime text`, and then applying to search and replace operations before you finally copy the resulting string and feed it to `pd.read_clipboard`.

The following snippet of code illustrates the point:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import io


text = """         A         B     Col #3
        NaN       NaN        NaN
  -0.041158 -0.161571   0.329038
   0.238156  0.525878   0.110370
   0.606738  0.854177  -0.095147
   0.200166  0.385453   0.166235"""


with io.StringIO(re.sub("(?<=[0-9]) +", "  ", re.sub("^ +", "", text))) as fs:
    df =  pd.read_table(fs, header=0, sep="\s{2,}",engine='python')


#           A         B    Col #3
# 0       NaN       NaN       NaN
# 1 -0.041158 -0.161571  0.329038
# 2  0.238156  0.525878  0.110370
# 3  0.606738  0.854177 -0.095147
# 4  0.200166  0.385453  0.166235
```

Thanks for asking the question.