# How to use space separated variable name in as.factor() to access data of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rpy2, unexpected-token, mass

**When did the problem arise?**

I was trying to use [polr()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-53/topics/polr) method of `R` (via `rpy2`) for ordinal regression analysis using the following statement. In that statement, "Number of Steps" is my dependent variable. When I set (in the column header and also in the statement) underscore replacing the spaces (i.e. Number_of_Steps), everything works fine.

```
model = mass.polr('as.factor(Number of Steps) ~ Var2',
                  data=df_data, method='logistic',
                  Hess = True)
# Here, mass = importr('MASS')
```

However, with spaces (i.e. Number of Steps), I get the following error.

> RRuntimeError: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :
> :1:17: unexpected symbol 1: as.factor(Number of

**How did I try to solve the problem?**

I have searched on google and also checked different questions in SO (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528198/how-do-you-handle-column-names-having-spaces-in-them-when-using-pd-read-clipboar)) related to this problem. However, still, I do not find the solution of this problem.

**Then, my question**

How can I use space separated variable name (i.e. column header) in `as.factor(variable name)` during use of `mass.polr()`?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to rpy2. In R, one can use backticks ( ` ) to delimitate a symbol that contains spaces.

Assuming your example is otherwise correct, the following should do it:

```
model = mass.polr('as.factor(`Number of Steps`) ~ Var2',
                  data=df_data, method='logistic',
                  Hess=True)
```

Demonstration:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

# Get an R data frame with a column name that has
# a space.
dataf = ro.r("""
require("MASS")
cbind(housing, "My Sat"=housing$Sat)
""")

print('column names:')
print(tuple(dataf.colnames))

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
mass = importr('MASS')
house_plr = mass.polr(
    ro.Formula('as.factor(`My Sat`) ~ Infl + Type + Cont'),
    data = dataf
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But in `rpy2`, still, I am getting an error `RRuntimeError: Error in is.factor(x) : object 'Number of Steps' not found`

Comment: That's a different error than the one the question bid about. It tells you that there is no column with that name in your data frame.

Comment: thanks for your response. I know that I should get such error only when this column is not available. However, despite having that column (checked by `df['Number of Steps']`),  I found this error after keeping Number of Steps inside `` (i.e. `as.factor(Grave Accent symbol Number of Steps Grave Accent Symbol )`).

Comment: You are not providing a complete example, but I suspect that your data frame is not what you hope it is. I added a self-contained example to show that this is working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your much effort. But I am sorry to say you that it does not work in my case. I have tried by converting pandas dataframe to dataframe of R, by using this statement `pandas2ri.py2ri(df_data)`. But still, I get same error.

Comment: It is much easier to try identify the source of an issue with a self-contained example. If the example I provide in my answer runs on your system, then I really think that your `df_data` is not what you think it is.